# SVG filter loses colour when the SVG is hidden or external

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

```html
<svg style="display:none">
 <defs>
  <filter id="blue-glow-display-none">
   <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" operator="dilate" radius="2" />
   <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" result="dilated" />
   <feFlood flood-color="#33ccff" />
   <feComposite in2="dilated" operator="in" />
   <feOffset dy="-1" />
   <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode />
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
   </feMerge>
  </filter>
 </defs>
</svg>

<svg style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">
 <defs>
  <filter id="blue-glow-position-absolute">
   <feMorphology in="SourceAlpha" operator="dilate" radius="2" />
   <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1" result="dilated" />
   <feFlood flood-color="#33ccff" />
   <feComposite in2="dilated" operator="in" />
   <feOffset dy="-1" />
   <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode />
    <feMergeNode in="SourceGraphic" />
   </feMerge>
  </filter>
 </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6801bf30e40c9f7972987d67e2d5e4f2?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG" style="filter: url(#blue-glow-display-none)" />
&emsp;
<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/6801bf30e40c9f7972987d67e2d5e4f2?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG" style="filter: url(#blue-glow-position-absolute)" />
```

The contents of the two SVGs are identical (save for a different ID), the only thing different is that one is hidden with `display:none` while the other uses `position:absolute` to remove it from view.

`display:none` causes the filter to not get its colour, resulting in black. This also applies when the SVG is loaded from an external file with `filter:url('/path/to/file.svg#blue-glow-external')`.

What's going on here, and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: You can't hide a SVG fragment containing a filter with display:none - CSS can't find it when you do that. This doesn't work at all in Firefox (and shouldn't work in Chrome - but the Chrome team is making Chrome more permissive in accepting stuff that "shouldn't" work.)

Comment: instead of using `display:none` try using  `width:1px;height:1px; position;absolute; right:-100px`

Comment: Oh, that's a little odd that it falls under things that "shouldn't" work... although I'm very confused why everything works except the colour. What about external files?

Comment: flood-color is a mapped CSS property.

Comment: @RobertLongson Oohhhh okay that makes sense. Somehow. I think it's very strange that it doesn't work, but I can sort of understand now.

Comment: Well display:none means no CSS at or below this element.